# How to create index on JSON field in Postgres for Sorting?

Tags: json, database, postgresql, indexing

I need to run the following query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM the_table ORDER BY jsonb_column ->>'json_property'
```

This query is slow, using sequential scan of all rows. I hoped that the following index can help speed things up:

```sql
CREATE INDEX data_sorting ON the_table ((jsonb_column->>'json_property') DESC NULLS FIRST);
```

It does not help at all, the index does not change the query execution.

How can I create an index that helps with sorting by a JSON property inside a `jsonb` column?

Comment: That index does work.  PostgreSQL doesn't use it as it thinks it will be slower than the alternative. If you set enable_sort to off, or add a small LIMIT, it should use the index.

Comment: your ORDER BY clause is ASC order by default while your index is DESC NULLS FIRST => Not consistent

Comment: ASC index does not work either.

Comment: @jjanes, setting the LIMIT on the query forces it to use the index.  You should make it an official answer!  Thanks!